# TS type for generalized onChange handler in form

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

Lets skip func declaration and so on, i will write my current types for state, and state itself

```
type BookFormState = {
  hasError: boolean;
}
BookForm<BookFormState> { ...
  state = {
   hasError: false
  };
```

then inside class i write generaized handler and call multiple inputs in component

```
onChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>):any => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

<form>
// ... multiple inputs ...
   <BookInput name="UNIQUE_NAME" value={this.state[name]} onChange={this.onChange} />
</form>
```

and i have error in onChange at [event.target.name]: event.target.value line

```
Argument of type '{ [x: string]: string; } is not assignable to parameter 
of type 'BookFormState | ((prevState: Readonly<BookFormState>, props:
 Readonly<BookFormProps>) => BookformState | Pick<BookFormState,
 "hasError"> | null) | Pick<BookFormState, "hasError"> | null'. 
Property "hasError", is missing in type {[x: string]: string;}, but
 required in type <PickrBookFormState, "hasError">.
```

So i end up with **NO** providing BookFormState in <> to component, and i just list all my imputs [name]`s in state name after name, and adress each one of them in props like value={this.state.title}.
But i guess thats not very good, but it works...

So what is the correct Type to correct that error above about {[x: string]: string;} ?  TS just doesn`t understand what comes to him in [event.target.name]: event.target.value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address `Property "hasError", is missing`, you can declare `hasError` optional. You should also include `UNIQUE_NAME` as well as any other input values you plan on tracking in state.

```
type BookFormState = {
  hasError?: boolean;
  UNIQUE_NAME?: string;
}
```

Comment: Well, yes! That works, though not quite sure why, thats not meant to be optional parameter...

also you suggested to add ```[key: string]: any;``` there, which has no impact, but if i write [key: string]: string, it says that boolean | undefined of hasError can not by assigned to string

Thank you!